# change default postgresql.conf location on ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, database-administration, postgresql-14

I can't seem to find a way to change the default location of `postgresql.conf` file from `/etc/postgresql/14/main/postgresql.conf` to `my/own/location/postgresql.conf`.
I am running postgresql on Ubuntu server.
I tried changing it using the postgres command line as per the docs but it gives the following error:

```
postgres=# ALTER SYSTEM SET config_file='/my/loc/test/postgresql/14/main/postgresql.conf';
ERROR:  parameter "config_file" cannot be changed
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The PostgreSQL documentation says:

> This parameter can only be set on the `postgres` command line.

So you can only change it when you start the server with

```sh
postgres -c config_file=...
```

This also gives you a clue how to go about it: you have to modify the systemd service file that starts PostgreSQL, ideally by creating a drop-in file in `/etc`.

Comment: `command not found: postgres`

Comment: There are the Unix commands `find` and `locate`. Also, I didn't suggest that you should start the server manually, I just tried to explain how the parameter is used.